# Excel VBA Comparing strings to ascertain whether contents of cell are in the correct format if they need to be

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, string-comparison

I'm creating a validation spreadsheet, where the user will input data before it gets imported into our company database.

I had it all finished, but then we realised there was one remaining hole, which I am struggling to plug.

For my test to see if I can get something to do what I want, the user enters data in columns A and B, starting at row 2.  Column A is mandatory, column B is a mix - for majority of entries in A then B is optional, but for certain entries in A then B is required AND is required in a predefined format based on A.

eg. 
user enters "12345678" in A2, and "12345678" is nothing special so an entry in B2 is optional
user enters "11111111" in A3, and "11111111" is special, so they do need to put an entry in B3, and it is required in the format ab12cde (??##???)

So far I have a small table in range N2:O6 to use for a Vlookup - N is the A entry (11111111, 22222222, etc) and B is the mask required (??##???, ##?#?, etc)

I know I will need to loop the code eventually, but I removed that as want to get 1 run-through done first.

```
Dim b As String
Dim suf As String
Dim zzz As Integer

Last_Row_Suf = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Debug.Print Last_Row_Suf

zzz = 2

If zzz <= Last_Row_Suf Then
    suf = "test"
    suf = Application.VLookup(Range("A" & zzz), Range("N2:O6"), 2, False)
    b = Range("B" & zzz).Value
    If suf Like b Then
        Range("D" & zzz).Value = 1
    Else
        Range("D" & zzz).Value = 0
    End If
    zzz = zzz + 1
Else
End If

    Debug.Print suf
    Debug.Print b
```

The issue I am facing is that Like is returning False when I try to compare for example xy45trn and ab12cde

I also need to put in the earlier steps to check if A2 is in the mandatory table or not as if it isn't then I will just skip as I don't care what is in B2 then, but suf doesn't get updated when the Vlookup fails.

Probably lots of issues, but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Should `Application.VLookup(Range("A" & zzz), Range("N2:O6"), 2, False)` be `Application.worksheetfunction.VLookup(Range("A" & zzz), Range("N2:O6"), 2, False)`?

Comment: You say: "The issue I am facing is that Like is returning False when I try to compare for example xy45trn and ab12cde". It is normal to return `False`. Please post here two such real strings which you want/need to be evaluated as 'True'. Ar those strings construction **all the time** built by two digits string, followed by two digits number and then three digits string?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am trying to compare AB123DEF to ??###???.  The format is not always the same, sometimes it will be comparing to ??##, sometimes to ?#?? etc

Comment: So, those are your real strings to be compared? If yes, `like` operator will never return `True`, I'm afraid. And, if you do not have a standard pattern to be compared, I am afraid also that nobody can help you... The comparing method must be changed, but referencing something clear. Even if there can be some different cases. But all of them to be clearly defined...

Comment: `?` will match any character, not just letters.  Likely you should use a "proper" regexp here instead of `Like`

Comment: @Mech - adding the `WorksheetFunction` will trigger a run-time error if there's no match.  Typically easier to leave that out and test the return value using `IsError()` to see if there was a match.

Comment: I was unaware you could omit that. `On Error Resume Next` is a bandaid which I'm not usually a fan of but would work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this::

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range, m, v
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsLookup As Worksheet

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsLookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config")

    'loop over the input in ColA
    For Each c In wsData.Range(wsData.Range("A2"), _
                               wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells
        'lookup table is on a separate sheet
        m = Application.VLookup(c.Value, wsLookup.Range("A2:B20"), 2, False)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a hit from the lookup table
            v = Trim(c.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            'using Like
            c.Offset(0, 3).Value = IIf(v Like m, "OK", "Error")
            'using RegExp
            'c.Offset(0, 3).Value = IIF(MatchesPattern(v, m), "OK", "Error")
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

If `Like` isn't meeting your needs then you can use a regexp object to perform the vbalidation: a bit more complex in terms of pattern, but much more powerful.

```
Function MatchesPattern(v, patt As String) As Boolean
    Static reg As Object
    If reg Is Nothing Then Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    reg.Pattern = patt
    MatchesPattern = reg.Test(v)
End Function
```

RegExp reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN